# How merge multi-line string within a pattern (but excluding the pattern)?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a comma separated CSV file (from the DB) but unfortunately the last field came as a double-quoted multi-line string, like this:

```
138749,CJIKMN,"d4IFtjCCBbIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBaMwggWfAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMG4GBmeBCAEBAaBk
BGIwYAIBADALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwTjAlAgEBBCAeyMDmgdZS30d5JSraWWoUX50J1vKONjxUYxK9
iPZWWjAlAgECBCCzqs7CzH7+3j3trSz+/dcCmud3/Jo9ZYFmN4VTvTjB56CCBBowggQWMIIDnaAD
Lp69+Z3QgAIgHOYjzAQlDRHnDJ/zDtlkWN5pq7T7h3ef9Mnv4ocSuAA="
136065,CIJEPY,"d4IF4jCCBd4GCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBc8wggXLAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMIGYBgZngQgBAQGg
gY0EgYowgYcCAQAwCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMHUwJQIBAQQgNQdsXvKebYUdH0JybzpY2evf+v9Xg86b
hkjOPQQDAjBBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEOMAwGA1UEChMFVUtLUEExIjAgBgNVBAMTGUNvdW50cnkg
LUxRjUXbTgfGwUKOFwemsc4KXbsLZ13MkbNfAQ=="
```

How can I merge those multi-lines, excluding the quotes, keeping the rest as it is? All I can came up with:
`sed '/\"/{n;:l N;/\"/b; s/\n//; bl}' sampleOut.txt` but that not what I was looking for. I'm looking for this instead:

```
138749,CJIKMN,d4IFtjCCBbIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBaMwggWfAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMG4GBmeBCAEBAaBkBGIwYAIBADALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwTjAlAgEBBCAeyMDmgdZS30d5JSraWWoUX50J1vKONjxUYxK9iPZWWjAlAgECBCCzqs7CzH7+3j3trSz+/dcCmud3/Jo9ZYFmN4VTvTjB56CCBBowggQWMIIDnaADLp69+Z3QgAIgHOYjzAQlDRHnDJ/zDtlkWN5pq7T7h3ef9Mnv4ocSuAA=
```

Any idea how do I do that? I'm okay with `awk` as well.

-San

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(will add explanation shortly).

```
awk '
/,\"/{
  val=$0
  gsub(/\"/,"",val)
  next
}
/\"$/{
  gsub(/\"/,"")
  print val $0
  val=""
  next
}
{
  gsub(/\"/,"")
  val=val?val $0:$0
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '
/,\"/{                 ##Checking condition if a line has comma with " in it then do following.
  val=$0               ##Assigning current line value to variable val here.
  gsub(/\"/,"",val)
  next                 ##Using next will skip all further statements.
}
/\"$/{                 ##Checking condition if a line is ending with " then do following.
  gsub(/\"/,"")
  print val $0         ##Printing variable val and current line value here.
  val=""               ##Nullifying variable val value here.
  next                 ##Using next will skip all further statements.
}                      ##Closing block for condition here.
{
  gsub(/\"/,"")
  val=val?val $0:$0    ##Creating a variable named val whose value is current line value and its concatenating its own value in it.
}
END{                   ##END section of awk is getting started here.
  if(val){             ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT NULL, if yes then do following.
    print val          ##Printing variable val value here.
  }                    ##Closing block of if condition here.
}' Input_file          ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I think you have assumed that particular field should be the last column, which may not be the case but I can live you that. I'd be rather interested in a solution that try to finds everything within a set a double-quote. I@m giving it a try and post back here.

Comment: @MacUsers, sure check and let me know if you have any other conditions in it, could edit solution then too.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual lines, that is all. With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]+"' -v ORS= '{gsub(/[\n"]/,"",RT); print $0 RT}' file
138749,CJIKMN,d4IFtjCCBbIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBaMwggWfAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMG4GBmeBCAEBAaBkBGIwYAIBADALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwTjAlAgEBBCAeyMDmgdZS30d5JSraWWoUX50J1vKONjxUYxK9iPZWWjAlAgECBCCzqs7CzH7+3j3trSz+/dcCmud3/Jo9ZYFmN4VTvTjB56CCBBowggQWMIIDnaADLp69+Z3QgAIgHOYjzAQlDRHnDJ/zDtlkWN5pq7T7h3ef9Mnv4ocSuAA=
136065,CIJEPY,d4IF4jCCBd4GCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBc8wggXLAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMIGYBgZngQgBAQGggY0EgYowgYcCAQAwCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMHUwJQIBAQQgNQdsXvKebYUdH0JybzpY2evf+v9Xg86bhkjOPQQDAjBBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEOMAwGA1UEChMFVUtLUEExIjAgBgNVBAMTGUNvdW50cnkgLUxRjUXbTgfGwUKOFwemsc4KXbsLZ13MkbNfAQ==
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution:

```
$ cat mac.txt
138749,CJIKMN,"d4IFtjCCBbIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBaMwggWfAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMG4GBmeBCAEBAaBk
BGIwYAIBADALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwTjAlAgEBBCAeyMDmgdZS30d5JSraWWoUX50J1vKONjxUYxK9
iPZWWjAlAgECBCCzqs7CzH7+3j3trSz+/dcCmud3/Jo9ZYFmN4VTvTjB56CCBBowggQWMIIDnaAD
Lp69+Z3QgAIgHOYjzAQlDRHnDJ/zDtlkWN5pq7T7h3ef9Mnv4ocSuAA="
136065,CIJEPY,"d4IF4jCCBd4GCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBc8wggXLAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMIGYBgZngQgBAQGg
gY0EgYowgYcCAQAwCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMHUwJQIBAQQgNQdsXvKebYUdH0JybzpY2evf+v9Xg86b
hkjOPQQDAjBBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEOMAwGA1UEChMFVUtLUEExIjAgBgNVBAMTGUNvdW50cnkg
LUxRjUXbTgfGwUKOFwemsc4KXbsLZ13MkbNfAQ=="
$ perl -ne ' chomp; if( /"$/) { s/\"//g;print $_,"\n" } else { s/\"//g; print } ' mac.txt  | nl
     1  138749,CJIKMN,d4IFtjCCBbIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBaMwggWfAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMG4GBmeBCAEBAaBkBGIwYAIBADALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwTjAlAgEBBCAeyMDmgdZS30d5JSraWWoUX50J1vKONjxUYxK9iPZWWjAlAgECBCCzqs7CzH7+3j3trSz+/dcCmud3/Jo9ZYFmN4VTvTjB56CCBBowggQWMIIDnaADLp69+Z3QgAIgHOYjzAQlDRHnDJ/zDtlkWN5pq7T7h3ef9Mnv4ocSuAA=
     2  136065,CIJEPY,d4IF4jCCBd4GCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBc8wggXLAgEDMQ0wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMIGYBgZngQgBAQGggY0EgYowgYcCAQAwCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBMHUwJQIBAQQgNQdsXvKebYUdH0JybzpY2evf+v9Xg86bhkjOPQQDAjBBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEOMAwGA1UEChMFVUtLUEExIjAgBgNVBAMTGUNvdW50cnkgLUxRjUXbTgfGwUKOFwemsc4KXbsLZ13MkbNfAQ==
$
```